# Find the ‘total sent’ for each JOB IDs in last 1 month along with ‘list name’ it was sent to

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting, query, sql, automationstudio

Currently by using this query, I get the number of total_sends for a particular JOB id.
But I want to modify the Query so that it shows total_sends , ListName , Date for that each job ID within a specified  timeframe.

```
Select 
count(s.EmailAddress) 
from [_Job] j 
join [_Sent] se 
on j.JobID = se.JobID 
join [_Subscribers] s 
on se.SubscriberID = s.SubscriberID 
where 
se.IsUnique = 1 and 
se.EventDate > dateadd(d,-20,getdate()) and 
j.JobID =11111
```

Here is the example of how my final Table should look like,
[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to aggregate the sent data and then join it with _ListSubscribers data view to get the list name.

This should do the work:

```sql
Select 
s.JobID,
count(s.JobID) AS [Emails Sent],
MIN(s.EventDate) AS [Sent Date],
l.ListName
FROM _Sent s
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ListID, ListName FROM _ListSubscribers) l
ON s.ListID = l.ListID
GROUP BY s.JobID, l.ListName
```

You will have to add all your filters to above query.

Reference:

COUNT: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_count_avg_sum.asp,

GROUP BY: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp,

_ListSubscribers: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_data_view_listsubscribers.htm&type=5